# Why don't posts show in Google+ Communities?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-communities

Posts made to a Google + Community don't immediately show in the Community:   even the community's owner's posts don't show.

After 4 to 5 hours the posts appear, but not in any order. The sort order is set to *Recent*, but posts shows randomly.